# Certificate is not found when WCF Application is hosted as a Windows Service on Windows 7

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-7, windows-services, windows-10

We have a WCF application which can be hosted both as a windows service or as a console application.

This application makes use of a smart card certificate to authenticate some requests to a third party application. We use the following logic to get the certificate from the windows certificates store:

```
public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string certificateName)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    X509Certificate2Collection sel = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificateName, false);

    if (sel.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception($"No certificate found with name: {certificateName}");

    X509Certificate2 cert = sel.OfType<X509Certificate2>().OrderByDescending(pX => pX.NotAfter).First();

    store.Close();

    return cert;
}
```

This code works nice on Windows 10, so we host the WCF as a Windows Service in our production environment when the customer has Windows 10 available.

But **on Windows 7 the certificate is not found when the WCF application is hosted as a Windows Service**. Because of this we are working it around by hosting the WCF application as a console application. We need to figure out why it doesn't work as a Windows Service on Windows 7, although it does find the certificate if the WCF Application is hosted as a console application on the same environment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason caused the failure of finding the certificate may be that the location of the certification. As you know, the condition that we search for the certificate is the current user, and the certificate store location is MY, the current user is the current login user.

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

While the user may be another user which is different from the current login user when we install the windows service.
[image]
So we had better search the certificate which is stored in the LocalMachine, and It could be found by any users.
Besides, we could use the Certlm.msc command to manage the certificates in LocalMachine.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Didn't work. Setting "Account" to be "LocalSystem" still gives the error of certificate not found. Is there something else I I need to do besides setting this property?

Comment: You could try to export the certificate to fox file and then imported the certificate to localmachine, at last we change the location where we search for the certificate to localmachine. Or you could set the account to USER and use the host\username as the credentials when you install the windows service

Comment: Pfx file not fox file

Comment: Sorry, the X509Store object instantiation was written diferent in my answer than it is actually in my code. I fixed it. Basically, my code uses only the StoreLocation parameter.

Comment: Got it, but I think exporting the certificate won't be a option, because it's installed on a Smart Card. So the certificate is only active on Windows while the SmartCart is connected on a USB Port. After removing it physically it's also automatically uninstalled from the Windows Store.